# Prototype method not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm creating a custom object on click and then trying to access it's prototype's methods.

```
$(function(){       
    $('.addtask').on("click", function(){
        var new_task = new Task();

        $('.deletetask').on("click", function(){
            new_task.deleteTask();
        });

        function Task(){        
         this.html="<li>Add Description<span class='deletetask'></span></li>";
        }

        Task.prototype = {
            constructor: Task,
            deleteTask: function(){
                this.remove()
            },
        }

    });     
});
```

Now when i click on class deleteTask it says:

```
TypeError: new_task.deleteTask is not a function


new_task.deleteTask();
```

How can I access the prototype method deleteTask() ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the prototype of `Task` **after** you've created your `new Task`. You're not changing the prototype of your already created instances by doing so, as the prototype is referenced at the instance creation.

Move the `Task.prototype = {` assignation **before** the creation of your `new Task`.

If you really want to add a function to all instances after they're created, change the prototype of the constructor instead of replacing it :

```
Task.prototype.deleteTask = function(){...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the definition of `Task` and its `prototype` methods before the initial `.on` call.  This will incidentally fix the problem identified by @dystroy whereby you're trying to set the prototype of `Task` after creating an instance of it.

As written the `Task` function is recreated every time the click handler is invoked, and therefore the `Task` objects created on each click will be instances of *different* classes, which makes using the `prototype` moot.  Prototype methods are an effective way of sharing methods amongst multiple instances, and achieving inheritance, but you're using neither.

Alternatively, leave the `Task` function where it is but abandon using `prototype` methods, e.g.:

```
function Task() {        
    this.html = "<li>Add Description<span class='deletetask'></span></li>";

    this.removeTask = function() {
        this.remove();
    }
}
```

(NB: `this.remove` is also undefined at this point?)